# Iniciar connectionString vacía y cargar al ejecutar el formulario c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-access, app.config

Tengo un problema con la propiedad connectionString en App.config debido a que inicialmente la necesito vacía. No puedo colocar una ruta a una base de datos pues el proyecto lo debo ejecutar en otros computadores y sobra decir que el error va a ser que no encuentra esa ruta.

Este es mi **app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Settings.SAFEConnectionString"
            connectionString=""
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Éste es el **error**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como al cargar el formulario ya con una función le doy un valor a connectionString, luego de la primera vez que aparece este error, le doy en continuar, cierro y vuelvo y ejecuto ya empieza a funcionar. No lo puedo entregar así, así que si alguien tiene una forma de ayudarme se lo agradezco de antemano. :)

Comment: y donde generas la nueva connexion? eso lo deberias hacer si la conexion esta vacia para evitar el error.

Comment: Algo está intentando leer el valor del connectionString antes que le des un valor, copia aquí el texto que aparece bajo "Detalles" (_stacktrace_).  Con eso podemos tener una pista de donde está ocurriendo el problema.

Comment: Diana, [edit] la pregunta y coloque el código que está usando.

Answer (score 1):

El error esta mas que claro, sino defines nada en el `app.config` esta claro que fallara, el tema es que minimamente debes poner algo por defecto

No se que tan dinamico sera la ruta, la idea de usa un .config es que peudas ditarla con el notepad y asignar el datos correcto despues de instalar

Pero si la db va a estar junto al .exe puedes usar el `|DataDirectory|`, este representa la ruta donde esta ejecuando la aplicacion

[Access connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/)

algo como esto

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\myAccessFile.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;
```

de esta forma puedes definir un connection string fijo que varia de forma dinamica segun donde ubiques la aplicacion